# How to reset the CookieAcceptPolicy setting for NSHTTPCookieStorage

Tags: wkwebview

I made a change to the CookieAcceptPolicy in NSHTTPCookieStorage in my app:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever];
```

When I use the following code to restore its settings:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain];
```

WKWebView still does not store cookies. I found that in iOS 17, the cookie policy for WKWebView can be enabled through the following configuration:

```
[[[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] httpCookieStore] setCookiePolicy:WKCookiePolicyAllow completionHandler:^{}];
```

But how can this be done in versions prior to iOS 17?